# Ruby on Rails - redirect_to the next video that is not marked as completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, logic, redirecttoaction

How can I redirect to the next lesson that does not have userLesson (problem is lessons belongs to a course through a chapter)

Models:

```
class Course
    has_many :lessons, through: :chapters
end

class Lesson
 belongs_to :chapter
 has_one :lecture, through: :chapter
end

class User
  has_many :user_lessons
end

class UserLesson
  #fields: user_id, lesson_id, completed(boolean)  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
end

class Chapter 
  has_many :lessons
  belongs_to :lecture
end
```

here user_lessons_controller:

```
class UserLessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user_and_lesson
  def create
    @user_lesson = UserLession.create(user_id: @user.id, lession_id: @lesson.id, completed: true)
    if @user_lesson.save
      # redirect_to appropriate location
    else
      # take the appropriate action
    end
  end
 end
```

I want to redirect_to the next lesson that has not the UserLesson when saved.  I have no idea how to do it as it belongs_to a chapter. Please help! Could you please help me with the query to write...

Comment: What do you mean by "that has not the UserLesson when saved"?.
Also add your lessons routes. Execute the following command:
`rake routes | grep lesson`

Comment: I want to redirect_to the next lessons that has not been completed yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your question:

Inside your user_lessons_controller:

```
def create
  @user_lesson = UserLession.create(user_id: @user.id, lession_id: @lesson.id, completed: true)
  if @user_lesson.save
    #You have to determine the next_lesson object you want to redirect to
    #ex : next_lessons = current_user.user_lessons.where(completed: false)
    #This will return an array of active record UserLesson objects.
    #depending on which next_lesson you want, you can add more conditions in `where`.
    #Say you want the first element of next_lessons array. Do
    #@next_lesson = next_lessons.first
    #after this, do:
    #redirect_to @next_lesson 

  else
    #redirect to index?? if so, add an index method in the same controller
  end
end
```

This code will only work if you define `show` method in your `UserLessonsController` and add a `show.html` in your views.

Also, in `config/routes.rb`, add this line : `resources :user_lessons`.